# query for number of array elements containing some field in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents that look like this:

```
{
   my_array : [
      { 
         name : "...", 
         flag : 1 // optional
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

How can I query for documents that **exactly one** of their elements contain the flag field?

This will return documents where `my_array` length is exactly 1:

```
db.col.find({ "my_array" : { $size : 1 } })
```

This will return documents where **at least one** of `my_array`'s object contain the flag field:

```
db.col.find({ "my_array.flag" : { $exists : true } })
```

And this will look for documents where flag is an array of size one:

```
db.col.find({ "my_array.flag" : { $size : 1 } })
```

I want to somehow combine the first two queries, checking for some inner field existence, and then querying for the size of the filtered array

Comment: Why is "flag" an integer field in the sample document? Perhaps I am missing something here.

Comment: my_array is an array of documents, each of those inner documents may or may not contain a field `flag` with some value (which is not important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$redact` with `$filter` for your query.

`$filter` with `$ifNull` to keep the matching element followed by `$size` and `$redact` and compare result with 1 to keep and else remove the document.

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [{
        $match: {
            "my_array.flag": {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    }, {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $eq: [{
                        $size: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$my_array",
                                as: "array",
                                cond: {
                                    $eq: [{
                                        $ifNull: ["$$array.flag", null]
                                    }, "$$array.flag"]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1]
                },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Comment: while this sounds like it may work, it'll require a full table scan, not using my index for "my_array.field", I've added a solution using aggregation that works, but I don't really like both solutions.

Comment: I should have mentioned about `$redact` not using index. I think these are pretty much two solutions you have. `$unwind` does add a memory overhead by unwinding each array. So depending on your data one can perform better than other. Not sure if this would be any different but you can change the solution to use `$project` and `$match` instead of `$redact`

Comment: You can also `{ $match : { "my_array.flag" : { $exists : true } } }` before `$redact` to filter the array before sending it through `$redact`. I have updated answer.

Comment: ok, i'll accept your solution as it contains less steps then mine. one thing I would have changed in your solution is `cond: { $gt : ["$$array.flag", null] }` which acts like `$exists`, and is more readable

Answer (score 0):

Use Aggregation framework in mongodb,

pipeline stage 1: Match ,

```
          checking for some inner field existence,

         { "my_array.flag" : { $exists : true } }
```

pipleline stage 2: Project,

```
         querying for the size of the filtered array,

         {$project:{ "my_array":{$size:"$my_array"}}}
```

mongoshell Command ,

```
    db.col.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            "my_array.flag": {
                $exists: true
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            "my_array": {
                $size: "$my_array"
            }
        }
    }])
```

Comment: the first stage won't **filter the array**, it'll match documents where at least one array element contains the flag. However, I think this can be done with aggregation, I'll try playing with it

Answer (score 0):

Following the current answers about using aggregate, here's a working solution using aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
{ $match : { "my_array.flag" : { $exists : true } } },
{ $unwind : "$my_array" },
{ $match : { "my_array.flag" : { $exists : true } } },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id", count_flags : { $sum : 1 } } },
{ $match : { "count_flags" : 1 } }
])
```

Here are the steps explained:

1. Filter to only documents that contain at least one `flag` field (this will use my index to dramatically reduce the number of documents I need to process)
2. Unwind the `my_array` array, to be able to process each element as a separate doc
3. Filter the separated docs from elements not containing `flag`
4. Group again by `_id`, and count the elements (that contain the `flag` field)
5. Filter by the new `count_flags` field

I don't really like this solution, it seems like a lot of steps to get something that should have basic support in a standard `mongo` `find` query.